# Database with revenue information for USA companies

Tags: market-data

I am going to start a project with an US company. I do not really trust them. I want to know if they are a "real" company. In some European countries you can consult some (often paid) databases and there you can see their yearly revenues, profit, etc. I tried to find something similar in the USA but did not find it. Any ideas?

Comment: If the company is financial firm, you can have a look at data in Bankers Almanac provided by Accuity. This database is paid.

Comment: If they're public, you should be sble to reference their 10K/Q with the SEC.  As for databases, if you're not paying...Compustat or Factset/Bloomberg are some of the usual suspects.

Comment: @Chris what is sec , 10k and q?

Comment: @open, google them